# ImageButton expands to wrap arround image

Tags: android, xml, imagebutton, android-gridlayout

I am trying to make a matchsticks game, so I need to create a grid of matchsticks.  Eventualy it needs to be bigger, but I am starting off small.  So, in case you're not familiar with the game, to start it looks like this:

```
 --   --   --
|   |    |    |
 --   --   --
|   |    |    |
 --   --   --
|   |    |    |
 --   --   --
```

where each `--` is a horizontal matchstick and each `|` is a vertical matchstick.  So, to create a one box version of that, I create a 3x3 grid which was then populated with horizontal matchsticks at (0, 1) and (2, 1) and vertical matchsticks at (1, 0) and (1, 2).  I did this using image buttons.  However, when I look at the design tab in the xml editor, I see that only the top right corner is fully visable, and the grid cells are huge.  I suspect that this is because the ImageButtons are expanding to wrap arround the two pictures, both of which are fairly large, so I was wondering if there is a way that I can force the ImageButtons to stay the same size and scale the pictures instead.  My xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/matchgame"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4" >
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:columnCount="3">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/matchstick_horizontal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/matchstick_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/matchstick_vertical"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_row="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/matchstick_horizontal"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="HH : MM : SS"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/playPause"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/button2"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do in your layout. You only have 4 buttons, but you want a 3x3 grid?

Comment: @Pztar I am intensionally leaving the corners empty so it looks nicer.

Comment: Your only option is to provide an image for each screen density. `drawable-xxxhdpi` where the image dimensions are `192x192` all the way down to `drawable-mdpi` where it's `48x48` You can find more information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have your drawable in varying sizes to be compatible with different viewports, the ratios are here: https://material.io/guidelines/layout/units-measurements.html#units-measurements-designing-layouts-for-dp at the bottom of the page.

You should start with the actual amount of pixels you want (for your purpose I would start with 48px) as the smallest image and then scale up as shown. These need to be placed in the appropriate res/mipmap folders with the exact same name. (the folders match the names on that website) For example in res/mipmap/xxxhdpi there should be "matchstick.png" and in res/mipmap/xxhdpi there should be "matchstick.png"  Then in xml you use `android:src="@mipmap/matchstick.png"` and it will automatically scale.

Then in xml code set your image widths and heights to 48dp. This way it will scale with devices appropriately and will look correct.

Comment: `mipmap` folders are meant for the app launcher icon. Not for images used in the app those belong in the `drawable` folders which follow the same naming scheme eg. `drawable-xxhdpi`

Comment: Actually I don't think that's true. Everything I have come across has said that if you need an image to scale it should be a mipmap. In this type of environment he is using the matchsticks as an icon and wants the experience to scale with the users screen, so I would use mipmap. Either way no matter what folder he is putting it in the solution to his problem is to scale the image to appropriate size.